# How to manual test an application that is mostly dependent on external services

Tags: development-environment

I'm working in a project that has a Java backend application and a React frontend application that are a single product.
Now, the backend fully relies on external services stored on AWS.
In dev, we can't use the AWS services because of cost constraints.
However, as a software engineer, I find difficult to imagine the big picture of an ongoing change without being able to test the whole trip from the frontend to the backend. So, just relying on tests and integration tests seems to be too less. I'd like to start backend and frontend in my localhost and see the magic happen.

What is the state of the art in this case? I was thinking about creating a server application that I can start locally to mimim the AWS endpoints we call.
Any better idea?